# How to download last version of all google drive files at scale?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

All my google drive files got encrypted by ransomware. Google did not help me with the backup of all drive files available before that encryption date.
The only option I found working is to manually select the file in Google Drive and revert to the previous version by deleting the encrypted current version. Google keeps the previous version of a file in drive only for 30 days.

I am looking for a script that can help me with reverting to the immediately previous version of the file by deleting currently encrypted at scale. I have 60 GB of data in Google Drive.

If you have any script to do that. I see in Google Developer documentation, they have opened Google Drive API for people where using API all versions can be set to forever saved or one can download a particular version of file using API.

I have left coding some 7 years back and struggling to create script. If anyone has such script created, it will help. Google drive is just my personal account.

Comment: I had the same problem last week and I have created an Apps Script which deletes the new file versions and keep the old version before the ransomware affected the Drive.
I am willing to share it with you as soon as I'll finish running the script on all my Directories... stay tuned :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem last week and I have created an Apps Script which deletes the new file versions and keep the old version before the ransomware affected the Drive.
Contact me for the Script.. for some reason I can't paste it here?!
You can Skype me (nickname: gozeril) and I'll give it to you.

Notes:

- You need to run it on each root folder one by one, changing in code the folder name only.
  ** Some folders are very big and therefore you must run the script several times
  The Script will run 30 minute at most.
  Be patient, it works!

I hope you'll find it useful :-)